# Popup - open form, submit data and return selected values

Tags: php, jquery, popup

I've install bPopup and have a simple popup configured on my `main.php` page:

```
  $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
              contentContainer:'.content', 
              loadUrl: 'test.php', 
              onClose: function(){ 
                  var name = $('#name').val();
                  console.log(name)
              }
  });
```

When the button is pressed `#element_to_pop_up` is shown and `test.php` is loaded. `test.php` contains:

```
SITE<br/>
NAME <input type='text' id='name' name='name' value=''><br/>
ID <input type='text' id='idd' name='idd' value=''><br/>
DESC <input type='text' id='desc' name='desc' value=''><br/>
<input type='submit' class="b-close" />
```

When the close button is pressed the popup closes and my console.log does show the value from `name`

What I'd like to do is have is

1. a `close` button that closes the popup **without** passing the values back
2. a separate submit button that submits the form to a database, closes the popup and returns the 3 values to the parents OnClose function.

I've created a [codePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vKzvQm) that shows the code so far.

Any one any idea how I can do this ?

Thanks

I am happy to consider a different plugin if that helps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test.php add two buttons with ID's

```
<input type='button' class="b-close" id='close' value='close'/>
<input type='button' class="b-close" id='save' value='save'/>
```

Change your onClose function to detect which button was selected and then set the onClose function to work with this.

```
 onClose: function(){ 
    var val = $(document.activeElement).attr('id'); // ID of selected button
    console.log (val)

    if ( val == 'close') { // close popup
       return false;
    }

    var name = $('#name').val(); // return values.
       console.log(name)
    }
}
```

New [**codePen**](http://codepen.io/Tom_T/pen/rLkbGo) showing this. 
Open the pen's console log, launch the popup and enter your name.

If you click save you should get your name shown in the console. If you click close you should get 'close' shown in the console.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your idea, it has helped. I'll mark it as the solution because it has helped move me in the right direction.